# Upgrading ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04 gave UI issues (updates/packages not installed while restarting I suppose)

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I upgraded ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04 using terminal commands. The upgrade was complete but while restarting, I might have closed the laptop to sleep mode. I starting it and while it upgrade is complete, the most of the UI is blocks. What should I do?

Comment: If you can open a terminal window try running something like `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. If there are unpacked but unconfigured packages it should hopefully sort them out. Might solve your problem or at least tell you if the package manager thinks all is o.k. or not.

Comment: @codlord Thanks, tried it. Did not solve. I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

worked for me